# How to change Iframe height when clicked on button inside the iframe's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Right now i want to make a simple jQuery function so when this function is called the iframe height is changing.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ChangeHeightF1() 
 {
    $("#inneriframe").css({"height":"350px;"});
    alert('The height was changed!');

 }
</script>
<div id="outerdiv">
    <iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no" target="_parent"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is the code of the button which is in the content of the iframe:

```
<button type="button" onclick="parent.ChangeHeightF1();">Click me to change Height!</button>
```

So my questions is how it's possible to change the iframe height on button click inside the content which is holding the iframe.

Also what CSS i have to place on "outerdiv" div element so when the iframe height is changing it will change the height of the div holding the iframe as well ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use window.parent.document as a context in jQuery selector, and then manipulate CSS values.

```
$(":button").click(function(){

    $('#inneriframe, #outerdiv', window.parent.document).css({"height":"350px"});

})
```

Comment: Do i have to asing ID to the button inside the content of the Iframe? I can do that. I want when this button is clicked to change the height of the iframe which is holding it.

Comment: Yes you can do it, just change the selector from $(":button") to $("#yourButtonID"). Remember that you you have to include this code INSIDE the page, which is going to be loaded in iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If you want to re size back to previous height, let me know.

`http://jsfiddle.net/ko3pyy8c`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#more').click(function(){
            $('#inneriframe').animate({height:'500px'}, 500);
            $('#more').text('Go Back');
         });
    });

</script>

<style type = "text/css"/>
    #inneriframe {
         height: 350px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<div id="outerdiv">
    <iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no" target="_parent"></iframe>
</div>
<br/>
<a href="#" id="more">Change Height</a>
```

Comment: The button is inside the iframe content. In your example you are creating another element which is next to the iframe. The button must be in the iframe content and when clicked to change the iframe's height.

Answer (score 0):

it can help you

```
 <a href='#'>click me</a>
<div id="outerdiv">
<iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no" target="_parent"></iframe>
```

by using jquery

```
    $('a').click(function(){
    $('iframe').css('height','600px');
});
```

Comment: The button is inside the iframe content. It's not next to the iframe as you are suggesting.